# Is there a way to get a mirror image ( horizontal/ vertical ) of a UIImage without degrading the quality of the image retured?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have used

`[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored]`

and

`[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];`

to get inverted images but the quality seems to be degraded.Is there a way to get inverted image without any degradation?

**I tried using**

```
-(UIImage*)getHoriMirror:(UIImage*)img
{
    CIImage* cii = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage];
    cii = [cii imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];
    CIContext *Context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [Context createCGImage:cii fromRect:[cii extent]];
    UIImage* uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return uiImage;
}
```

to get inverted images, but it also degraded the output.
Any help?

Comment: I have check above code and its not degrading any image quality can you post some screen shot of image where its degrading quality ?

Comment: it doesn't do that when this func is applied once, but if you do it around 10-15 times, it does, can you please check it after doing it for 10-15 times?

Comment: why does [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored] degrade the image quality?